# How to get Expanded child view in ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

[image]

I have 2 Button and one ExpandableListView in my activity.On button click i need to get Child views which is expanded in expandable List view. In other way i need to get all the child views which is currently showing in expandable List. For your reference i have added some sample image. in that i have get count button. on click of getcount button i need to get which is expanded(Dell) and its child and that count also.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample code and show, maybe, a graphical example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Eric Tobias added graphical example for reference.

Comment: @GrIsHu I try to get the count value from the child.In the child view onClick of Add button the count will automatically increase. if i get the child view i can able to get the count from the TextView - getText().

Comment: Ok let me imagine your code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you do not add extra buttons. Without code it is hard to give you an example of what to change in your code.

However, I would suggest you take a look at [`ExpandableListView#OnChildClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener.html). The method should offer the functionality you are looking for. I quote the documentation:

> **Parameters**
>
> `parent`  The `ExpandableListView` where the click happened
>
> `v`       The view within the expandable list/`ListView` that was
>   clicked
>
> `groupPosition`   The group position that contains the child that was
>   clicked
>
> `childPosition`   The child position within the group
>
> `id`  The row id of the child that was clicked

This should be sufficient to serve your needs!